# Horizontal menus in css/HTML

Tags: html, css, list, menu

Hi so I am creating a website, but I am troubled a bit with the footer menu - It only becomes horizontal when I use float:left (but after crossing a certain point it creates a new line). If I use anything other than float:left it becomes vertical. My goal is to make it all on a single line. Example in the image (my goal is to make the footer menu horizontal like my top menu) https://i.gyazo.com/61f2f5f7c0e6d98ad181364365163dd4.png

Here is the code I used. Footer code based on menu code:

```
#menuPan{width:736px; height:36px; position:relative}

#menuPan ul.menu{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:736px; overflow: hidden; background-color:#3f3f3f;}
#menuPan ul.menu li{height:36px; margin-right:5px; float:left; font-size:large; }
#menuPan ul.menu li a{height:36px; display:block; display: inline-block; color: white; text-align: center; padding: 8px 10px; text-decoration: none;}
#menuPan ul.menu li a:hover{height:36px; background-color: #6d6d6d;}
```

And my footer code:

```
#footer ul.footertest li{height:20px; float:left; font-size:large;}
#footer ul.footertest li a{height:20px; display:block; display: inline-block;  color:darkslategrey; text-align: center; padding: 8px 10px; text-decoration: none;}
#footer ul.footertest li a:hover{height:20px; background-color: #6d6d6d;}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you talk about the certain point? You should check the width of your footer menu< because, if it doesn't contain a lot of elements it shouldn't create second line.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying

```
display: inline-block;
```